# uninitialized constant RubyVM::DebugInspector seen in official Rails getting started guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, rubygems

I am a new user to Ruby on Rails, and I've been following the official getting started.

Platform: Windows 10
Ruby 2.2.4
Rails 4.2.5.2

What I am doing:

> rails new myapp 
> cd myapp 
> bundle install 
> rails server

Then I get this error:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\AAA\myapp>rails server
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/lib/binding_of_caller/mri2.rb:21:in `callers': uninitialized constant RubyVM::DebugInspector (NameError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/integration/cruby.rb:28:in `set_backtrace_with_binding_of_caller'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from C:/Users/MyUser/AAA/myapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have already tried uninstalling `debug_inspector` and running `bundle install` after, but the problem persists.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If it is still actual. Try to add debug_inspector to your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bundle the gem before start rails server. Follow following steps:

```
rails new myapp
cd myapp
bundle install
rails server
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all versions of debug inspector first:

```
gem uninstall debug_inspector
```

then installed it again with the `arch -arm64` flag

```
arch -arm64 gem install debug_inspector
```

For some reason, it required to install another gem (which may not be necessary for you)

```
arch -arm64 gem install rbs -v 2.1.0
```

And after that, the error has gone.